# Special characters show up as a question mark in magento admin header

Tags: magento

I installed the new theme in Magento and it worked well in front end.
 Everything was ok.
After some time (about an hour), I was asked to look at admin page.. It was strange.. 
Lot of special characters as a question mark are being display on the top of the admin header page.
I can log in to admin.. everything is fine.. but these special characters are making me die.
 please help me out. I m using Magento 
I am not able to post screenshot due to reputation score..here I m placing some of the error strings:
mj*s��y���������·����]�������ʻϢ��*���К���⪺�ʾ�������������-$(5�23E$81u3y9XMO/gUG�I�Onfjwsa��~����QUj??AD�������{z�����������������+j-!��',,$8)=�,�6K�QV;~;�?RfWk>E�E�IxhLZ�\P1�$$&),��LWV���������Ĵ����ƌŋ������䬦��������&++#7(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is exactly happening with your theme.

Have you copied any theme files in `app/design/adminhtml` or `skin/adminhtml`?

if then kindly check with another Magento installation.

refer this : http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-install-magento-theme-ultimate-magento-theme-tutorial/

If you trying to login in chrome then try with Firefox.

Delete the folders `var/cache` and `var/session` then give try.

Cheers :-)